# Checking if user exists without making GET user?email={email} public

Tags: react-native, rest, system-design

I am trying to implement Apple Id auth for my react-native app. The issue is that the API Apple provides acts as both login/registration and the responsibility of checking if the user exists lies on the developer.

I was thinking of checking if GET users?email={user_email} returns non 404 status code, but that would mean that it opens up an endpoint of finding user by email to the public. That is undesirable.

Is there a way to check if a user exists without opening up an endpoint of users to the public?

Comment: So if you don't want to make the endpoint open to the public, who should be allowed to access this endpoint?

Comment: Sorry, I meant open without any secrets. We do authentication through jwt, so everything is protected through that except for login, obviously. I see opening up an endpoint without any secret such as jwt as a security vulnerability.

Comment: JWT tells you (presumably) that a specific user registered. What benefit would a JWT give you here? To rephrase: who is allowed to access this endpoint, and more importantly... who isn't?